# npm install fails at Failed at the grpc@1.20.0 install script

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, npm-install, grpc

I am trying to do `npm install` for an angular project and this is the issue I am facing

```
> grpc@1.20.0 install D:\professional-workspace\Gentrick\Risco\risco-web\node_modules\grpc
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library

node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.20.0/node-v72-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.20.0 and node@12.16.1 (node-v72 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
```

then

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! grpc@1.20.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.20.0 install script.
```

Environment:-

```
windows: 10 64x

node: 12.16.1

angular CLI: 7.3.9

angular: 6.1.10
```

I have tried installing python as well but that didnt help either.

Comment: *npm install grpc --verbose*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That version of grpc is not compatible with that version of Node. You can fix that by using a newer version of grpc or an older version of Node. The newest version of grpc at this time, 1.24.2, is compatible with Node 12.x.

Answer (score 3):

Its not supported in the latest version of node, gyp is supported in 11.x version. I was facing same issue. I installed version node-v11.15.0 and it build successfully. Revert current version of node, download from here [node-v11.15.0](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v11.x/)